Android Compose WindowInsets work's wrong for ModalBottomSheet in ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE
Problem: I'm encountering an issue with the ModalBottomSheet component in Jetpack Compose. When displaying the ModalBottomSheet in landscape orientation, the insets appear to be incorrect, causing layout problems.
In portrait orientation, the ModalBottomSheet displays correctly and respects the insets, but when switching to landscape orientation, the ModalBottomSheet doesn't adjust properly and has incorrect insets. This results in part of the content being cut off or the sheet not appearing where it should.
UPD: I've already identified the issue and created this task for future reference, in case others face the same problem. Additionally, I intend to create an issue on Google Issue Tracker and need this for explanation.
see image before fix
see image after fix
Kotlin: "1.9.10"
Compose settings:
composeOptions {
    kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion = "1.5.3"
}

Version of libraries that I use:
1. "androidx.compose:compose-bom:2024.05.00"

2. "androidx.compose.material3:material3:1.2.0"

3. "androidx.core:core-splashscreen:1.0.1"

4. "androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.9.0"

5. "androidx.activity:activity-ktx:1.9.0"

6. "androidx.activity:activity:1.9.0"

App Theme:
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <style name="Theme.AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
        <item name="android:navigationBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
        <item name="android:forceDarkAllowed" tools:targetApi="q">false</item>
    </style>

    <style name="Theme.Splash" parent="Theme.SplashScreen">
        <item name="windowSplashScreenBackground">@color/main</item>
        <item name="windowSplashScreenAnimatedIcon">@drawable/ic_splash</item>
        <item name="postSplashScreenTheme">@style/Theme.AppTheme</item>
    </style>
    
</resources>

Android Manifest:
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <application
        android:name=".App"
        android:allowBackup="false"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        tools:targetApi="34">

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.Splash">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>

MainActivity: (please note that I use FragmentActivity, but the problem appears with other type of activities too)

class MainActivity : FragmentActivity() {

    private lateinit var splash: SplashScreen

    @OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        splash = installSplashScreen()
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        enableEdgeToEdge()
        
        setContent {
            AppTheme {
                val configuration = LocalConfiguration.current
                val sheetState = rememberModalBottomSheetState()

                ModalBottomSheet(
                    sheetState = sheetState,
                    sheetMaxWidth = configuration.screenWidthDp.dp,
                    onDismissRequest = {},
                    content = {
                        Box(
                            modifier = Modifier
                                .fillMaxWidth()
                                .height(100.dp)
                                .background(Color.Cyan)
                        )
                    }
                )

                Box(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .fillMaxSize()
                        .background(Color.Red),
                    contentAlignment = Alignment.Center,
                    content = {
                        LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
                            delay(3000L) // just for test
                            splash.setKeepOnScreenCondition { false }
                        }
                    }
                )
            }
        }
    }
}

How to fix it:
Ah, the joys of using "stable" and latest libraries! It turns out even Google's officially published libraries have a few surprises for us. Turns out, the solution is to change the versions of the following libraries (because who doesn’t love a good game of library version roulette?):

You need to update version of these libraries:

"androidx.core:core-splashscreen:1.0.1" -> "androidx.core:core-splashscreen:1.2.0-alpha01"
"androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.9.0" -> "androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.8.0"
"androidx.activity:activity-ktx:1.9.0" -> "androidx.activity:activity-ktx:1.8.0"
"androidx.activity:activity:1.9.0" -> "androidx.activity:activity:1.8.0"


You must add this in you build.gradle.kts(:app), because some other libraries could override yours.


configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.force("androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.8.0")
    resolutionStrategy.force("androidx.activity:activity-ktx:1.8.0")
    resolutionStrategy.force("androidx.activity:activity:1.8.0")
}


Well this is a super bummer, I just came looking because I'm having the exact same issue with a Dialog composable in landscape (scrim has the same behavior), oddly though, AlertDialogs they're deprecating don't have this problem. Did you submit an issue or ticket to Google? Can confirm still an issue with androidx..activity 1.9.3, coreKTX 1.15.0. Really wish they'd quit breaking stuff.

I decided to check my ModalBottomSheet in landscape and mine isn't set to be full-screen width, but check out the odd content padding that's always on the same side as system nav, in case helps your case: https://i.ibb.co/NTb4tvz/Screenshot-20241222-023235.png and https://i.ibb.co/PjrBb3b/Screenshot-20241222-023257.png

Also if this helps, here's a screen-grab of layout inspector in Android Studio showing that Dialog() has correctly sized itself, but is positioned wrong in landscape: https://i.ibb.co/2ymqtC4/dialog-wrong-pad.png
